# Elegant way to split an xpath output into two variables to insert it into a database

Tags: python, database, xpath, lxml, libxml2

We have a code which extract the service list from our tomcat server and insert it into a database. Basically, the code will receive a huge output ( 100+ results ) from a html result with the following structure:

```
<TABLE bgcolor=#dddddd border=1>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>name</B></TD>
<TD>Loader</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>enabled</B></TD>
<TD>true</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>loadok</B></TD>
<TD>13</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE bgcolor=#dddddd border=1>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>name</B></TD>
<TD>tester</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>enabled</B></TD>
<TD>false</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>loadok</B></TD>
<TD>13</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Following, the actual code ( which works )

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import psycopg2
import urllib2
import base64
import sys
import re
import lxml.html as LH

con = None

try:

    con = psycopg2.connect(database='xx', user='xx',password='xx',host='vxx')
    cur = con.cursor()
    qry ="select iservers.env,iservers.family,iservers.prefix,iservers.iserver,iservers.login,iservers.password,services.service,"   +\
    "proxy_access.proxy_server,proxy_access.proxy_user,proxy_access.proxy_pass "        +\
    "from services,iservers,proxy_access where iservers.env='TEST' and services.id='2' "
    cur.execute(qry)
    data = cur.fetchall()

    for result in data:
    
        env      = result[0]
        family   = result[1]
        prefix   = result[2]
        iserver  = result[3]
        login    = result[4]
        password = result[5]
        service  = result[6]
        proxyHost = result[7]
        proxyUser = result[8]
        proxyPass = result[9]

        proxy_auth = "http://"+proxyUser+":"+proxyPass+"@"+proxyHost
        proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http": proxy_auth})

        opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
        request = urllib2.Request("http://"+iserver+service)
        base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (login, password)).replace('\n', '')
        request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        html = response.read()
        
        ###################### CHANGE THIS TO USE A HTML PARSER
        regex = r"name</B></TD>\s<TD>(.*?)</TD>\s</TR>\s<TR>\s(.*)enabled</B></TD>\s<TD>(.*)</TD>"
        for m in re.finditer(regex,html):
            print "inserting\t"+iserver+"\t"+m.group(1)
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO pereirtc.package_status (env,family,iserver,prefix,package,status) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(env,family,iserver,prefix,m.group(1),m.group(3)))
            con.commit()
        ###################### END
except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
    print 'Error %s' % e
    sys.exit(1)

finally:

    if con:
        con.close()
```

After some help from Stack Overflow, I was advised to change the block on "change this ...." to libxml. So I got the following block to use:

```
  doc = LH.fromstring(html)
  tds = (td.text_content() for td in doc.xpath("//td"))
  for td, val in zip(*[tds]*2):
      if td in ("name","enabled"):
          print (td,val)
```

With the example above, I have the result:

```
('name', 'Loader')
('enabled', 'true')
```

And what I want is, to insert the result using xpath to insert it into a database. Since I'm starting on python, I'm blocked on how I can do that with xpath/libxml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you meant the following simple operation, but splitting the result into two variables is achieved as follows:

```
doc = LH.fromstring(html)
tds = (td.text_content() for td in doc.xpath("//td"))
for td, val in zip(*[tds]*2):
    if td == "name":
        name = val
    elif td == "enabled":
        enabled = val

print name
print enabled
```

Comment: Hi,

I tried your solution and only returned 4 results ( total is 120 )

If i put the print name/enabled inside the for loop i get the error "NameError: name 'name' is not defined "

Comment: Hi, worked on your solution after inserting the print inside the if condition :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that:

```
blah = [('name', 'Loader'), ('enabled', 'true')]
blahd = dict(blah)
cursor.execute('insert into blah (name, enabled) values(%(name)s, %(enabled)s)', blahd)
```

Or, not using named values...:

```
cursor.execute('insert into blah (name, enabled) values(?, ?)', [i[1] for i in blah])
```

Comment: I forgot to tell about the values from name, and enabled are dynamic. its a list of services.

Any way to make Loader and true from 
    blah = [('name', 'Loader'), ('enabled', 'true')]

Receive the values from the td ?

Comment: @ThalesPereira err, so what is your DB schema then?

Comment: Then create a tuple/sequence with PACKAGE and STATUS as the second element of what I've called blah... Or, if the DBAPI has the .executemany method, use that...

Comment: for the first sugestion i got 100 insertions of the same value ( loader, true )

for the second sugestion it returned the error:
Error syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ... into pereirtc.package_status (package, status) values(?, ?)

Comment: @Thales For the 1st, you are looping over your list of objects and executing an insert, right?

Comment: Exact. i think im not making myself clear because english is not my native language. I think i will update the first question with the whole code. and re-do the question.